# How to change value at location pointed by iterator

Tags: c++17

I want to know how we can change or replace the value pointed to by an iterator at a particular location. For example:

```
vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5};
auto it = max_element(v.begin(),v.end());
```

This iterator will be pointing to location of element having value 5.
I want to replace this value, how can i do it using iterator.

Just expecting simple solution of above question.

Comment: `*it = <someValue>;`? What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: I have tried  it=(*it)+1, got compile error.

Comment: `*it = (*it)+1`, or simpler `*it++`. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/s497G5jhn

Answer (score 0):

`*it = 7;` There are exceptions, but most of the time you're supposed to pretend an iterator is just a pointer.

Comment: can you tell some of exceptions.

Comment: `const int *ptr = ...;` is different from `const iterator it = ...;` because `ptr` may be mutated (as in, the pointer `ptr++` to point to the next element is valid), it marks the pointed-to value constant. A `const iterator it` makes the iterator const, so you can't mutate it `it++;` is a syntax error. Instead classes like `vector` has a `const_iterator` class which acts like a const pointer.

Comment: `std::list` is a linked list, so while its iterators point to the value, it doesn't make sense to `++` them or to take a difference between two of them. With pointers that's never a syntax error, but it's a syntax error to do `auto it = l.begin(); it += 2;` on a linked list iterator.

Comment: Pointers are built in to the C++ language, but iterators are objects written by programmers who were told "make your iterator object act like a pointer, as much as possible". `vector` and `list` are part of the C++ standard library, but they're still objects whose code you can read. People who write their own software and write their own data structures may end up writing their own iterators for them too. We ask that people make them act like pointers, but there's nothing to enforce it.